# UIPrintInteractionController borderless printing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprintinteractioncntrler, uiprintformatter

[image: A3]

I am working on the iPhone app using print image concept using **UIPrintInteractionController**. I have stuck at one point i.e. **border**, whenever I tried to print any image using printer it always show border on all sides which is not required. Image should use whole the paper size, as I am giving the image size same as paper width and height, but still it is showing border.

I didn't find any kind of method to remove the border or make the paper content border less. See iPhone image [image] [image]

You can see in the attached image [image], In this I am trying to print the image from Mac system in which it is giving option for border and border less.

I think it should be there in the **UIPrintInteractionController** **framework**, but didn't find anyone.

Please help me, if someone has experienced regarding this.

Thanks in advance. Your help will be appreciated

```
[![A4][4]][4]
```

[image: A3]

Comment: On macOS the printer provides borderless paper sizes.

Comment: @Willeke but in the iPhone  application, it doesn't show the option for paper size and borderless.

Comment: Look into choosePaper: delegate method

Comment: @Sulthan Can you provide any sample code. Requirement is just that margins shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to eliminate any borders you could quickly achieve that by passing a `photo` outputType to a printInfo object:

```
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
printController.printingItem = someImage
printController.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers = true

let printInfo             = UIPrintInfo.printInfo()
printInfo.outputType      = .photo
printController.printInfo = printInfo
```

---

[image]

Now, if you want greater control over the final rendering, you could explore [Apple's sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PrintWebView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010311-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) regarding `UIPrintInteractionController`

Comment: It's works only for A4 page size, not for others and print preview never give the option to choose paper size, how to get that

Comment: I am accepting your answer, it is working 70% fine but not for all papers.

Comment: @MinkleGarg Can you provide a mini project demonstrating the problem? Do you use a custom `UIPrintFormatter` / `UIPrintPageRenderer`?

Comment: I have added two images in the question, one is A4 and other is A3, When I load the image of A4 size then it is working fine, but suppose user has selected A3 options before print preview in custom option, then the print preview is not correct.

Comment: This worked for me for specialty 54x86mm paper. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

**Objective-C** version

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
printController.printingItem = someImage;
controller.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers=YES;

UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto;
printController.printInfo = printInfo;
```

Comment: UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto  used for best quality output for images